# Complexheatmap column annotations r

Tags: r, heatmap, complexheatmap

I would like to use anno_summary for the columns containing continuous variables (split by a categorical variable). By default, this function yields boxplots with means and SD.

I was wondering, is it possible to somehow get medians and IQR to appear? In the code below, there is anno_boxplot introduced, however the question remains the same.

Thanks,
Ag

```r
data1 <- as.data.frame(dati[, c(3:6)])   

column_ha <- HeatmapAnnotation(" " = anno_boxplot(data1,
                                                  height = unit(4, "cm"),
                                                  gp = gpar(fill = 1:10)))
        
Heatmap(scale(data1), name = "Legend", column_names_rot = 360, 
        cluster_columns = FALSE, column_title = c("Drug exposure"),
        width = unit(50, "mm"), split = data.frame(tscc = data$tscc),
        row_title = c(">60 days", "<60 days"),
        row_dend_width = unit(2, "cm"),
        bottom_annotation = column_ha)
```

Comment: Hi there! Adding some code so that people can quickly reproduce the output that you are showing will help a lot in onboarding them to help out. Look at the `dput()` function to get the data into the code.

Comment: I suggest putting that code up in to the question via "Edit" function. Also you may want to have a look at how code blocks can be styled (backticks), which will make for much easier reading.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I have accordingly updated the question.

Comment: What remains is having `dati` avaibale. If its private data maybe you can obfuscate it in some way to make to code runnable out-of-the-box. If the example code does not run right away people will be reluctant to help because they can't reproduce the problem easily.